# Python module not found after pip install

Tags: python, pip

Important info: Windows 11 OS, IDE VSCode, Python 3.12.0
I installed the pdfkit package with pip and tried to write a script to convert an epub file to pdf. I followed the standard 'pip install [package] procedure. However, the package is not working when running my script.

I checked it was installed with 'pip list' and it does show as installed. Below is the error I am getting:
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\Users\%USER%\Desktop\epub_to_pdf.py", line 1, in <module> import pdfkit ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdfkit'`
Any ideas on what is happening. This only started happeinging after the new python update and am unsure if this is related. I did attempt a reinstall of python.

Comment: 100% of the time this is caused by multiple python installations ... make sure you are using the right python and do something like `C:/my_project/.venv/python -m pip install ... `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It most probably the case of wrong virtual environment.
To identify this issue, you can follow following steps.

Please note run all command in cmd

1. activate your virtual env (my virtualenv name is free)

   C:\Users\6507433>workon free
2. run command "where python" It will give list of all python.exe available.

   (free) C:\Users\6507433>where python
   C:\Users\6507433\Envs\free\Scripts\python.exe
   E:\vinaydata\installation\python27\python.exe
   E:\vinaydata\installation\Python38\python.exe
   C:\Users\6507433\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
3. Run your code using virtual env python

   (free) C:\Users\6507433>C:\Users\6507433\Envs\free\Scripts\python yourcode.py